# How to set relative path of the browser driver to the system properties in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea

I need to pass a paths of the Firefox and Chrome drivers, which are stored in my resource directory (/src/main/resources/drivers).

[image]

For example, to get a Firefox driver (geckodriver), I'm passing a full path to the system properties:

```
private static WebDriver getFirefoxDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "/home/alex/Programming/Automation/Selenium_practice/mailru/src/main/resources/drivers/geckodriver");
    return new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

But to make this project exportable, I need to pass relative path to geckodriver.

How to do this?

Comment: Java an file paths.. always confusing. For my own project, it works when using a relative path that starts at the projects root. For you, that would something like "./src/main/resources/drivers/geckodriver". (I wouldn't put the binary in a 'src' folder btw, its not source file).

Comment: Oh yeah! That works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Java and file paths.. always confusing.

For my own project, it works when using a relative path that starts at the projects root. 
For you, that would something like `"./src/main/resources/drivers/geckodriver"`.

Side note: I wouldn't put the binary in a 'src' folder btw, its not source file.

Answer (score 0):

Java file paths for a driver can be written as relative path with respect to the project root.
`"./"` states parent folder under root(project)
so if the parent folder inside of project is `resources/drivers` then the path would be like

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "./resources/drivers/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe");`